# check and add div inside div at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

i have div in .aspx page:

```
<div id="mainWrapper" runat="server">
</div>
```

iwant to append div in run time.
In page load i try

```
mainWrapper.append("<div id="headerLeft"></div>");
```

but i am unbale to check if div `id="headerLeft"` already exist or not.if not then only append div.Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about server-side or client-side code?

Comment: @SLaks thanks to edit my Q.I m talking about server side code.Thanks.

Comment: Although i got down vote still i m waiting for ans bcz i lost my whole day for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `mainWrapper.FindControl` to check if the div already contains the other one and you add the inner one with `mainWrapper.Controls.Add` only if not exists.

but anyway, if you do something like this:

```
protected Page_Load(...)
{

 if(!IsPostBack)
 {
  // ... add the inner div...
 }

}
```

you would add the inner div only once.

Comment: all div are append at run time so how `find control` check div is already exist or not.

Comment: runtime and client side or server side are "different" things!!

Comment: @atticae beside `div id = mainWrapper` all are adding at run time.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. Maybe you should consider an alternate solution for whatever problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery

```
  if ($("#headerLeft").length=0){
        $("#mainWrapper").append('<div id="headerLeft"></div>');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be much simpler to just hide the headerLeft until you need it? ASP.NET will not output any HTML when the `Visible`-Property is set to false:

```
<div id="mainWrapper" runat="server">
  <div id="headerLeft" runat="server" Visible="false"></div>
</div>
```

Then in the code you can just:

```
headerLeft.Visible = true;
```

That way you can also easily check if the div is already visible.

Comment: its a part only D:).div r generate at runtime.show n hide is not a problem.Main problem is div are exist or not?